# Always on/Background application Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: background-process, windows-phone-8.1

I need my application to run a task in the background. I'd like to know if there is a way to do this without the user having to launch the application first.

Also I need the Background Task to display a page when a condition is reached and this page should take priority over anything else which might be on the screen at that moment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By all means anything of this is impossible on WP

Comment: AFAIK you have to first register a background task, which means that you have to run your app first. Note that you may [lauch your app with associated uri or file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779673.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Technically this is not possible in Windows Phone Platform, however you could use BackgroundWorker to perform background tasks.

Comment: I would advise to use *Task.Run* instead of *BackgroundWorker*. The second thing is that it won't help the OP, unless it's fired inside the [BackgroundTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx), when you run it from UI, it will likely be stopped when you navigate away from the App.

Comment: @Romasz
Thanks.
I'm thinking of using a toast notification and then use that to navigate to the required condition.
I do now have the code samples to make the task work in the background but it requires the application to be launched by the user first.
Is there a way to launch the background task if the app is pinned as a Live Tile?